# Убрать скобки foreach

Tags: javascript, php

как мне убрать в foreach эти скобки http://prntscr.com/10nckan ?
Из за этих скобок js выдает ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ']'

```
name: "Парк",
    style: "islands#redIcon",
    items: [
        <?php $park_loop = CFS()->get( 'park_loop', get_the_id() ); ?>
        <?php if (is_array($park_loop)) { ?>
            <?php foreach ( $park_loop as $key => $field ) { ?>
                {
                    center: [<?php echo $field['park_loop_coordinates']; ?>],
                    name: "<?php echo $field['park_loop_title'];?>"
                },
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    ]},
```

Comment: **json_ecode()** вместо всего этого ужаса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас изначально неправильный подход работы с массивами. Попробуйте использовать `json_encode()` – функция возвращает строку, содержащую JSON-представление для указанного `value`. А после уже работаете с данными, полученными в JSON, через JavaScript, использую `JSON.parse()`.

Ниже привожу пример PHP-функции из реального проекта, которая отдаёт JSON. Вы можете адаптировать её для собственных нужд:

```
function autosuggest() {
    $results = query_posts([
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'showposts' => 10,
        's' => $_POST['search']
    ]);

    $response = [];

    if (!empty($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $response[] = [
                'link' => get_permalink($result->ID),
                'title' => $result->post_title
            ];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Comment: а зачем stripslashes?

Comment: @Ипатьев вы правы, здесь излишне. Спасибо за внимательность)

Comment: я бы сказал что использовать stripslashes вообще излишне, в любом случае. у этой функции нет применения в современном языке.

Comment: @Ипатьев вообще-то да, надо избавляться от привычки везде ставить stripslashes.

Comment: Безопасность здесь не при чем. К безопасности эта функция вообще никогда не имела никакого отношения. Ее единственное предназначение было - исправлять данные, испорченные криворуким программистом. Если в данных вдруг встретится избыточное экранирование, то надо сделать так, чтобы его изначально не было. То есть исправлять причину, а не бороться с последствиями

Comment: @Ипатьев не всегда получается бороться с фронтом)